# "Amend" 2 merge commits

Tags: git, merge

Imagine I need to merge 2 branches into my current branch. I first merged the first branch and hence created a merge commit with 2 heads. I've now merged the second branch without creating the merge commit yet.

Is it somehow possible to amend the previous merge commit, so it will get 3 parents?

```
o [HEAD] Merge2
|\                 o Modified Merge1
o \ Merge1         | \
|\ \               |\ \
| o | A            | o | A
| | |              | | |
| | o B            | | o B
. . .              . . .
. . .     ==>      . . .
. . .              . . .
|/  |              |/  |
o  /               o  /
| /                | /
o                  o/
.                  .
.                  .
.                  .
```

Comment: Why do you want that to happen anyway?

Comment: And finally, you do realize that commits are immutable, and when you edit them, you're just making new commits with a different history?

Comment: @MadPhysicist : Wrong on a number of points.  But correct to ask why this would be desirable.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can't actually edit commits, but that they will be recreated parallel. I want to know whether this step-by-step merge is possible, because I have seen a repository where a merge commit had >2 parent commits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A commit with more than 2 parents (an octopus merge) is likely to be a bigger headache than it's worth.  But there are ways to get from here to there.

Since you're in the middle of your merge work locally, I'm assuming you haven't yet pushed the first merge.  That means a history rewrite that erases it may not be a big problem.  So you have some options.

If neither merge conflicted, then perhaps the default octopus merge strategy would have worked.  In that case you can go back to the starting state.  Since it sounds like you're in a merging state you'd start with

```
git merge --abort
```

Then undo the previous merge

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Then do the octopus merge

```
git merge A B
```

The problem with this approach is that the octopus merge strategy won't even attempt to deal with conflicts.  In that case you would do the merge in two steps - as you have - and then you could manually create the final merge commit, replacing the two "normal" merge commits with it.

But at this point I'm going to again say, are you sure you would want that?  Especially in a case where there were conflict resolutions, it seems like you'd be throwing information away.

Well, if you choose to go ahead and do it, there are several ways.  This is not the "easiest" necessarily, but it avoid plumbing commands:

Go ahead and commit your 2nd merge.  Then maybe create a temporary tag.  (If you're comfortable with the reflog, you maybe don't need this tag.)  Then go back to your pre-merge state.

```
git tag merge_goal
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

Next initiate a three-parent merge, but (1) avoid conflicts by using the "ours" strategy, and (2) don't commit, because the "ours" strategy won't have produced your desired merge result.

```
git merge --no-commit -s ours A B
```

This will set you up to create the desired parent list for your new commit, but you still need to get the content right.

```
git rm -r .
git checkout merge_goal -- .
git commit
```

And now you can delete the temporary tag, if you created one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So an octopus merge can't be done in several steps but one needs to know in advance?

Comment: @ThomasS. : If you mean, is there a git command to take an existing merge and another branch, merge in the branch, and replace the existing merge (with a new merge that has an additional parent) instead of producing a new merge?  No.  The procedure for doing that is manual, and it is the 2nd procedure I describe above.

Comment: Maybe a command that unifies 2 neighboring merge commits with each 2 parents to 1 merge commit with 3 parents?

Comment: @ThomasS.: Once again, there is no built-in support for what you're asking.  The 2nd procedure above is one of the simpler (i.e. porcelain) ways that includes steps to combine two adjacent 2-parent merges into a 3-parent merge.